# Why is my method called twice in Framework7 on click?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-framework-7

I'm using Framework7 and I'm trying to just make a fairly simple button click setup that triggers an alert window. The setup is as follows:

[image: Setup picture]

```html
<div class="col-100">
  <div class="list no-hairlines-md">
    <ul>
      <li class="item-content item-input">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="item-title item-label">Custom Message</div>
          <div class="item-input-wrap">
            <input id="custom-message-input" type="text" placeholder="Your message here..." />
            <span id="custom-message-clear" class="input-clear-button"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <a id="custom-message-button" class="button button-raised button-fill">Send Custom Message</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the click event is initialized like so:

```js
app.on('pageInit', function (page) {
  $('#custom-message-button').on('click', () => {
    $('#custom-message-clear').click();
    app.dialog.alert('Message was successfully sent.', 'Information');
  });
  ...
```

But for some reason, when I click the button, it triggers twice. The alert appears once, I click it away, then it appears again, and I click it away. Then it stays gone.

What might I be missing here?

Comment: Not familiar with that frameowrk but I would do some logging inside `on('pageInit'` and see if it gets called more than once. Worst case you can do `$(selector).off('click').on('click'....`

Comment: @charlietfl I checked. It prints out my console message twice when I click the button once.

Comment: Understand that part but does pageInit get triggered more than once to cause it?

Comment: @charlietfl The weird thing is, I do something that is exactly the same on another page, yet that gets triggered just once.

Comment: @charlietfl It would seem that pageInit does indeed get called twice. But weird it works as intended somewhere else then :/ I'll try and check and see if I can find out where the other call is.

Comment: Presumably it gets called for each page in the app no? As I mentioned above you can try using `off()` then `on()`. Or add a class to the button first init and check for that class

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah that might be what it is. I'll try and check for that.

Comment: @charlietfl Solution found; I read the 'page' object and check the 'name' property. Then I can tell what page it is calling init on and then just ready click events per page init. If you want, you could make an answer here that points out that it's because pageInit is called for every page found in the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone should stumble upon this in the future; It's because "pageInit" is called for every page that is found in the router. Use the "name" property to figure out what page is currently being initialised.